# About a normal HID keyboard sending Interrupt packet

Tags: keyboard, usb, fpga, hid

I use FPGAs to implement USB1.0 phy and application layer.
The application is debugging with a normal Logitech K120 keyboard.
Now, I could send a SETUP packet to light up the NUM, CAPS and SCROLL lock LED with no problem.

But when I send a INTERRUPT packet to enable device report, the bus is to wait, and then get timeout fail.

SET Configuration is 1.

The INTERRUPT packet is as follows:

```
< SYNC ><  IN  ><ADR0 > EP1 CRC5
00000001100101100000000100000101
< 0  8 >< 9  6 ><  0  ><1 ><CRC>
```

Why could it not work?

I would really appreciate it if you would help.